# Azure Function how to move appsettings from local to server and vice versa

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app-proxy

I m a little new to Azure.

Issue is I m developing Azure Functions and some times I have to work locally (code/ test etc) and other times on Azure. Every time I switch I have to compare and change app settings manually.

Is there a way I can avoid it ? Something where if I run locally I may get latest from server without manual and when I go to server Azure may be aware of my changes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) —

```
Usage: func azure functionapp <action> [-/--options]

fetch-app-settings  Retrieve App Settings from your Azure-hosted
                    Function App and store locally Aliases:
                    fetch-app-settings, fetch
```

and

```
Usage: func azure functionapp <action> [-/--options]

publish             Publish the current directory contents to an
                    Azure Function App. Locally deleted files
                    are not removed from destination.

    <FunctionAppName> Function App name

    --publish-local-settings [-i] Updates App Settings for the
                                  function app in Azure during deployment.

    --publish-settings-only [-o]  Only publish settings and skip the
                                  content. Default is prompt.

    --overwrite-settings [-y]     Only to be used in conjunction with -i or -o.
                                  Overwrites AppSettings in Azure with local
                                  value if different. Default is prompt.
```

There's also encryption for the local file if you feel a little adventurous — 
run `func settings` to get usage.